# Import wp users via one click demo option

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, users

I have created a WordPress theme and added an option to import demo data in which I have added WordPress posts, pages, customize options. when my client buy the theme and use one-click demo option to import demo data so that their site looks exactly my site with dummy images and content.

Recently I have created new Member Directory site using Ultimate Member plugin, where I need to add wp users also in one click demo option, I have tried googling but could not find what I want,  all are showing with plugins and export and import.

I only need to add this in one click demo, I used this plugin for one click demo options: https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-demo-import/

Any can guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Users data are part of Wordpress XML import file as Ultimate Member support explained [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/export-data-users-of-form-registration-ultimate-member/), I think you will need to activate Ultimate Member plugin first to ensure that the data are imported properly.

Comment: The url you provided is seperate plugin which works for import and export users, but not have an option to integrate into one click demo option.